# Adding a list to a file submenu in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-menu

The variable `ports_available` contains an array of COMPORTS. I want these to be added to the submenu "ports_menu" on startup of the GUI so that I can select any one of them for selecting the COMPORT.

```
global ports_available
ports_available = [comport.device for comport in serial.tools.list_ports.comports()]

global port_select
port_select = "COM1"

#Create Menu
my_menu = Menu(window)
window.config(menu = my_menu)

# Add Tool Menu
tool_menu = Menu(my_menu, tearoff = False)
my_menu.add_cascade(label = "Tools", menu = tool_menu)
tool_menu.add_command(label = "Bold", command =bold_it)
tool_menu.add_command(label = "Italic", command =italic_it)

#Menu for ports

ports_menu = Menu(tool_menu, tearoff = False)
tool_menu.add_cascade(label = "Ports", menu = ports_menu)

for name in ports_available:

    ports_menu.add_checkbutton(label = name, variable = port_select)

[![When i select any one of the option everything gets selected][1]][1]
```

Thank you,
Dhruv Gupta

Comment: You can get the answer to this by reading existing documentation. It's not clear why you need our help. Please [edit]  your question to include a [mcve] which illustrates the problem you're having.

Comment: I read the documentation and everywhere add_cascade command is showing. I have a list which is changing every time i start the tkinter app and accordingly the submenu should be updated.

Comment: What is stopping you from updating the submenu each time it starts? Please show what you've tried.

Comment: I have updated the question, requesting you to have a look at it. Thanks.

Comment: I went to this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20429448/tkinter-how-to-create-submenus-in-menubar) which you posted long back. In that I have added the list to the submenu but how to access those values separately. I have three different ports in the list and want to select any one from it and load the value into a variable.

Comment: Why aren't you simply iterating over `ports_available` to add items to the menu?

Comment: I did that i guess and edited the code. But what should i do to store only one of the value from the options when i select it from the sub-menu ?

Comment: Are you wanting a command, or do you want to set the value of a variable? Both of those are also documented. Are you aware you can add radiobuttons and checkbuttons to menus?

Comment: I want to set the value of the variable. No, I don't know about the radio buttons or check buttons in menus.

Comment: They are all documented. Look for `add_checkbutton` and `add_radiobutton`.

Comment: Thank you so much @BryanOakley the radio buttons were really useful. It worked how i wanted it to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments you posted, what you're wanting is to set a variable based on a menu selection. You can add radiobuttons to a menu with `add_radiobutton`. The use of radiobuttons will allow the user to make an exclusive choice.

Here's an example:

```
import tkinter as tk

ports = ["COM1", "COM2", "COM3"]

def show_value():
    print(f"selected port: {port_selection.get()}")

root = tk.Tk()

port_selection = tk.StringVar(value=ports[0])
menubar = tk.Menu(root)
port_menu = tk.Menu(menubar)
for port in ports:
    port_menu.add_radiobutton(label=port, value=port, variable=port_selection, command=show_value)

root.configure(menu=menubar)
menubar.add_cascade(label="Port", menu=port_menu)

root.mainloop()
```