# tkinter nested menubar python

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Wanted:
menu: file -> names->1.name1 2.name2:

This my code:

```
   menubar = Menu(window)
    filemenu = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
    filemenu.add_command(label="names")

    submenu = Menu(filemenu, tearoff=0)
    submenu.add_command(label='name1')
    submenu.add_command(label='name2')

    menubar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=submenu)
```

But I get file->1.name1 2.name2

What should be my fix ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Tkinter - How to create submenus in menubar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20429448/tkinter-how-to-create-submenus-in-menubar)

Answer (score 0):

Try this.
If you want to know which one was selected, use `radiobutton`

```
from tkinter import Tk, Menu

# root window
root = Tk()
root.geometry('320x150')
root.title('Menu Demo')


menubar = Menu(root)
root.config(menu=menubar)

# create the file_menu
file_menu = Menu(
    menubar,
    tearoff=0
)

sub_menu = Menu(file_menu, tearoff=0)
sub_menu.add_radiobutton(label='name1')
sub_menu.add_radiobutton(label='name2')
file_menu.add_cascade(
    label="name",
    menu=sub_menu
)

# add Exit menu item
menubar.add_cascade(
    label="File",
    menu=file_menu,
    underline=0
)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Do you know if I can add 'V' before chosen option ? for example, name1 @Sujay

Comment: @alex, you mean to say you want to show some sign in front of the option selected?

Comment: Right. yes. @Sujay

Comment: @alex check the answer

Comment: Is it possible that it already loads with sign ? I mean: show the default choice. @Sujay

Answer (score -1):

You need to make "names" a cascade off of the file menu.

```
filemenu = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
menubar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=filemenu)

submenu = Menu(filemenu, tearoff=0)
filemenu.add_cascade(label="name", menu=submenu)

submenu.add_command(label="name1")
submenu.add_command(label="name2")
```